# Upload file through Web App - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "IP":80

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

My situation is like this:
I have a portal that is using web services to send requests to various providers and receive responses from them.
My users are connecting to the portal and i am preparing their requests to be sent to the providers and present them the response. 
Of all the transactions that are taking place there are also some file uploads. Generally we dont have problems but on a new provider while everything is working as expected when the user is trying to upload a file, we get this exception:

> message:Unable to connect to the remote server InnerException:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it myserverpublicIP:80
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) 
>   HResult:-2146233079 
>   Data:System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal 
>   Source:System 
>   message:   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
>      at GroupamaWebService.GroupamaWebServiceMethods.UploadFiles(List`1& docs, Int32 applicationNumber, String circulationNumber, String instanceId) 
>   message:Byte[] DownloadDataInternal(System.Uri, System.Net.WebRequest ByRef)

This happens on the production server. When i am trying to perform the same activity from my development computer everything works fine. 
The server doesn't have a firewall that could be blocking the request(dont ask me why, it's not my decision) but anyway all the other requests are passing along just fine. 
Also from my computer and accessing the portal using its public IP i still got no problem in uploading a file.
The server does not use proxy for accessing the Internet, it's just connected to a router/modem that's giving access to Internet
The server has malwarebytes home premium antivirus installed(no firewall also) and a quick search on google didnt result any related matter.

So my questions are:

1. i think that my server and not the provider's is blocking for some reason the upload, is that correct?
2. If i am correct in my previous assumption and if there is no firewall, for what other reasons would the server "actively refuse" the connection?

Edit: 
Problem "solved".

There was nothing wrong with my application or whatever I implemented to upload the file. For some reason the dll of the published application responsible for uploading the file was not ok. That was a really vague statement so i ll come back with more info when i get them.

Comment: are you able to telnet that on 80 port?

Comment: @शेखर I can when using the same gateway as the server does but when I use other (as most of users do) I get "...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed"

Comment: @शेखर wrong answer on my previous comment. When i am in the same gateway i get the "Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed", but when i am connected to internet with other gateway then it connects